# How can I extract columns from a workbook, using OPENPYXL considering only expecifc values in otrher rows

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I HAVE THIS SITUATION BELOW (FOR EXAMPLE):

[WORKBOOK CASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVdiq.png)

I'VE USED THIS CODE TO TRY EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM CELLS IN COLUMNS: A,C,D. BUT ONLY THE ONES THAT HAVE THE VALUE '1' IN 'DEFAULT' (COLUMN B) ROWS COMBINED WITH THE VALUE 'SOLTEIRO' PRESENT IN ROWS OF COLUMN: G (ESTADO_CIVIL);

i've tried this, but I'm new in this, and kind a stuck it here. Someone help?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb= load_workbook('credito.xlsx')
ws= wb.active

mylist= []
for row in ws.ite

r_rows(min_row= 2, max_row= 2):
    for cell in row:
      if cell:
        cell!= 1
        mylist.append(cell.value)
print(mylist)
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT [ask] and also [mre]

Comment: I'm sorry bout'it... New in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when you use "CAPS", it is generally considered as raising your voice or shouting. That is probably not what you meant. So, please be careful next time :-)

For your problem, you can use `worksheet.iter_rows()` to go through each row from 2 to `max_row` and use the first 7 columns as per the attached picture. Check if the default is 1 AND the last column is 'soltiero'. If true, add it to the list. Finally print it... Updated code below. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb= load_workbook('credito.xlsx')
ws= wb.active

mylist= []
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row= 2, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=7):
    if (row[1].value == 1) & (row[6].value == 'soltiero'):
        mylist.append([row[0].value, row[2].value, row[3].value])
print(mylist)
```

**Output** will look like this with some dummy data

```
[[13212417, 53, 'M'], [13212419, 56, 'F'], [13212431, 68, 'F']]
```

Comment: Sorry for shout, it was not my intention, thx my friend, You did great!